# Rspec expect(instance) to receive method not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, rspec-expectations

```
#controller file
def update
  @payment = Payment.find_by(reference_id: params[:reference_id])
  if @payment.update(update_params)
    @payment.do_something
  end
end
```

when trying to spec if do_something method was called, by

```
expect(@payment).to receive(:do_something)
```

it says

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

do_something is in my Payment Class. It is actually being called, but rspec says not.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to stub the lines in controller in order to `expect` some code

```
before do
  allow(Payment).to receive(:find_by).and_return(payment)
  allow(payment).to receive(:update).and_return(true)
  allow(payment).to receive(:do_something)
end
```

Also, instance variable in controller won't be directly accessible in rspecs.

So, First create a payment object in rspecs using `let` and use it `before` block like I did it in above solution

Comment: it works, but in my opinion faking ActiveRecord makes tests prone to many false positives

Comment: its working with me well after used your concept, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your @payment in specs is actually a totally different variable, which is part of specs class, not the controller. I may be wrong, but that is my assumption from the parts of code you post - add specs code for more info.
As of the solution, may use 'stub any instance'

`Payment.any_instance.stub(:do_something).and_return(:smthing)`

A more complicated approach - using doubles

Comment: is this equivalent to `allow_any_instance_of(Payment).to receive(:do_something).and_return(:smthing)`?

Comment: now I see that `any_instance` is deprecated (see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance):

any_instance is the old way to stub or mock any instance of a class but carries the baggage of a global monkey patch on all classes. Note that we generally recommend against using this feature.